# How to keep screen on with ProgressDialog?

Tags: android, window, progressdialog

I have a ProgressDialog running, and I don't want that the screen goes off while this ProgressDialog is running. What should I use? Should I use a Windows Feature, or something like that?

Comment: you can use setKeepScreenOn(boolean flag) on any view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution.

You should use something like that:

```
progressDialog.getWindow().addFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON );
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

type the following line oncreate method

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: That is going to make my activity make the screen on, not the ProgressDialog.

Answer (score 0):

Certain apps need to keep the screen turned on, such as games or movie apps. The best way to do this is to use the [FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON) in your activity (and only in an activity, never in a service or other app component). For example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
  }
```

The advantage of this approach is that unlike wake locks (discussed in [Keep the CPU On](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#cpu)), it doesn't require special permission, and the platform correctly manages the user moving between applications, without your app needing to worry about releasing unused resources.

Another way to implement this is in your application's layout XML file, by using the [android:keepScreenOn](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#keepScreenOn) attribute:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Using `android:keepScreenOn="true"` is equivalent to using [FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON). You can use whichever approach is best for your app. The advantage of setting the flag programmatically in your activity is that it gives you the option of programmatically clearing the flag later and thereby allowing the screen to turn off.

> Note: You don't need to clear the [FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON) flag unless you
>   no longer want the screen to stay on in your running application (for
>   example, if you want the screen to time out after a certain period of
>   inactivity). The window manager takes care of ensuring that the right
>   things happen when the app goes into the background or returns to the
>   foreground. But if you want to explicitly clear the flag and thereby
>   allow the screen to turn off again, use [clearFlags()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#clearFlags%28int%29):
>   `getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON).`

See more at: http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#screen

Comment: Got it. But can't I use the flag in my dialog? Because I want the dialog to make the screen on, and not the activity.